# Failed to parse a color from red

Tags: parsing, colors

I am attempting to compile the following example from a video tutorial:

```
from manim import *

from colour import Color
class BasicAnimations(Scene):`

    def construct(self):
    polys  = VGroup(
               *[RegularPolygon(5, radius=1, fill_opacity=0.5,
                             color=Color(hue=j/5, saturation=1,
                luminance=0.5)) for j in range(5)]
                ).arrange(RIGHT)
        self.play(DrawBorderThenFill(polys), run_time=2)
        self.play(
            Rotate(polys[0], PI, rate_func=lambda t: t), # rate_func=linear
            Rotate(polys[1], PI, rate_func=smooth), # default behavior
            Rotate(polys[2], PI, rate_func=lambda t: np.sin(t*PI)),
            Rotate(polys[3], PI, rate_func=there_and_back),
            Rotate(polys[4], PI, rate_func=lambda t: 1 - abs(1-2*t)),
            run_time=2
        )
        self.wait()
```

However, I have encountered the error which you can see below:

```
C:\tools\Manim\Lib\site-packages\manim\utils\color\core.py:147 in __init__  |
`|    144         elif hasattr(value, "get_hex") and callable(value.get_hex):  `                                                                   |
|
|    145             result = re_hex.search(value.get_hex())                  |
|    146             if result is None:                                       |
| >  147                 raise ValueError(f"Failed to parse a color from {val |
|    148                                                                      |
|    149             self._internal_value = ManimColor._internal_from_hex_str |
|    150                 result.group(), alpha 

ValueError: Failed to parse a color from red
```

Comment: Try to run this code: https://hastebin.com/share/ixolulejot.scss and please let me know if it works, not an expert in this, but tried to find the issue. I replaced the usage of the Color class with a direct reference to a Manim color constant (`BLUE_D`). You can replace `BLUE_D` with any other Manim color constant or RGB/hex color value.

Answer (score 2):

since we watch the same manim tutorial, I also happened to encounter the same problem.  Already tried to install lower version of colour module but the problem remains unsolved.

So this color-setting method works for me.

```
# Set colors based on j size
polys.set_color_by_gradient(*color_gradient([RED, YELLOW, GREEN, BLUE,], len(polys)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys i met this problem as well, i guess that the modules conflict with each other at some small details, so we need to wait the author to fix those bugs.       And i think the lower version may have no that bug but i havent try that mathod.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick:

```
def myHSV(hue, s = 0.96, v = 0.98):
            # hue should be in degrees i.e. 0 to 360
            return ManimColor.from_hsv([hue/360,s,v])
```

The arguments for ManimColor.from_hsv() should all be 0<arg<1; the numbers above (.96, .98) are just my preferences. The use of degrees in myHSV is just to echo the foundations of hsl and hsv. Call it with e.g.  myHSV(240). (Not quite hsl but it probably does the job you want.)